# stuck on creating a new object

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a new object called item1, which belongs to the StockItem class. I have already created the constructor for a StockItem inside the class file, making all the variables public, however i am now trying to create a new instance of it, but want the variables to be entered by a user, using the scanner class.

How would i go about creating a new instance of my objec? I have created the scanner class too, and got it to read input, but not recognise that the input i am typing is an attribute of a new item.

Any help would be much appreciated please, thanks.

```
StockItem Constructor:

public StockItem (String itemID, String itemDesc, Double price, int quantity, int reOrderLevel)
{       
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.reOrderLevel = reOrderLevel;
}
```

Code for scanner input:

```
else if (i==1)
    {


        StockListInterface.doAddItem(item);





        System.out.println("Add New Item");
        System.out.println("****************");

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter ID    :>");            
        String itemID = scanner1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Description    :>");
        String itemDesc = scanner1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Price    :>");
        String price = scanner1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Quantity    :>");
        String quantity = scanner1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Re-Order Level    :>");
        String reOrderLevel = scanner1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter another? (Y/N)    :>");



    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well in order to make a new object, you just take the class,

```
StockItem item = new StockItem("", "", 0.0, 0, 0);
```

this will load the new object with all null variables.

in order to use your scanner class to update each item, you just do the following:

For updating the item ID

```
System.out.println("Enter ID    :>");            
String itemID = scanner1.nextLine();
item.itemID = itemID;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this:

```
StockItem stockItem = new StockItem (itemID,  itemDesc,  Double.valueOf(price),  Integer.valueOf(quantity),  Integer.valueOf(reOrderLevel));
```

Comment: when i do that i get the error: "Cannot find symbol". It doesn't recognise my variables.

Comment: it's because, you might have passes Strings in stead of Double and int values.

Answer (score 1):

Then create an object using the constructor;

```
Double priceVal = Double.parseDouble(price);
int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
int level = Integer.parseInt(reOrderLevel);

StockItem stock1 = new StockItem(itemID,  itemDesc,  priceVal,  qty,  level);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
StockListInterface.doAddItem(item);
```

Add after:

```
 System.out.println("Enter another? (Y/N)    :>");
```

the code:

```
StockItem item = new StockItem(itemID, itemDesc, Double.valueOf(price), 
 Int.ValueOf(quantity), Int.ValueOf(reOrderLevel));
StockListInterface.doAddItem(item);
```

assuming StockListInterface.doAddItem retrieves an argument of StockList.

Answer (score 0):

> I have already created the constructor for a StockItem inside the
>   class file, making all the variables public,

This is a very bad idea.  Those variables should be private.

You're making the classic newbie mistake of mingling user interactions where they don't belong.  It's a two step process:

1. Get all the values from user
2. Create the instance

The constructor need not know or care where the values you pass to it came from.